# What's the difference between 'atomic' and non-atomic?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Atomic vs nonatomic properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties)

I just want to know what is the differneve between theses two lines of code :

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *str;
```

and

```
@property(atomic, retain) NSString *str;
```

Thanx,
Regards,
tek3

Comment: Here is answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32942413/1961064

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Atomic properties are necessary in a reference counted multi threaded environment in order to stop objects from disappearing before a thread has a chance to retain them.

Consider the naive implementation of a get accessor:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject 
{
    id myPropertyIVar;
}
-(id) myProperty;

@end

@implementation MyObject

-(id) myProperty
{
    return myPropertyIvar;
}

// other stuff

@end
```

This is all fine except that if you release the instance of MyObject before retaining the returned value from -myProperty the returned value may well be deallocated.  For this reason, it is safer to implement -myProperty like this:

```
-(id) myProperty
{
    return [[myPropertyIvar retain] autorelease];
}
```

This is now completely safe in a single threaded environment.

Unfortunately, in a multithreaded environment there is a race condition.  If the thread is interrupted at any time before the retain has incremented the retain count, either of the following will cause you to receive a garbage pointer:

- the instance of MyObject is released and deallocated by another thread causing the ivar to be released and deallocated
- myProperty is reassigned by another thread causing the old version to be released and deallocated

For this reason, all accesses to the property must be protected by a lock.  The get accessor looks something like this.

```
-(id) myProperty
{
    // lock
    return [[myPropertyIvar retain] autorelease];
    // unlock
}
```

The set accessor is similarly protected and so is the release in -dealloc

Comment: Thanx a lot JeremyP. I really gleaned a lot from your answer.

Comment: Not quite the full story. :) An atomic property does not actually guarantee thread safety.  It only guarantees that you'll get/set an integral value.

Comment: @bbum: Ha, I knew I should have put that bit in too.  In my defence, you'll notice that I haven't even claimed atomic properties guarantee thread safety, only that it makes it *possible* to get a property safely in a multithreaded environment.

Answer (score 2):

The Apple docs explain all this very well. To learn about properties, including their atomicity, read [this page](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Articles/ocProperties.html).

Comment: This link is dead, consider revising.

Comment: 2015 link is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html