# List of objective-C terms

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to teach myself objective-C and I'm running to all these terms that are unfamiliar like mutable and atomic. I've been googling for this for a while now and can't seem to find a page that has a bunch of definitions all in one place. Does anyone have a link to a page that has table/cheatsheet with common objective-C terms and definitions.
Also, a page that translates objective -C terms to java terms would be really helpful too.
Thanks :]

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what you can't get from the documentation as far as terms go? First search on 'mutable objective c' takes me to a huge reference by Apple...

Comment: first of all I was searching for the wrong things, I was searching "objective-c mutable property" and reading the first few results of that wasnt giving me what I needed. And second. I want to print out a table style list of definitions and keep it next to me while I read the apple tutorials, so I dont have to do a search each time I run into the terms. But Thanks @dans3itz, I can get what I need fast enough by searching the way you mentioned, so I dont need a cheat sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm quite a noob to objective-c myself, but here are some basic terms that took me a while to understand. Most books tend to overcomplicate their role or purposes, creating ambiguity for a learner.

- *mutable*: "changeable", can be changed, as opposed to "immutable."
- *receiver*: an object that receives a message
- *message*: a method
- *instance*: invoked when needed, as opposed to variables/methods that are compiled at runtime regardless
- *atomic,nonatomic*: deals with how certain elements in your code are dealt with memory, such as properties. As far as I know, a beginner doesn't really need to worry about these, as a lot of memory management is handled by objective-c's ARC (automatic reference counting).
  I found a SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332216/whats-the-difference-between-atomic-and-non-atomic) if you are interested in reading more.
- *interface*: usually denoted with ".h" file extension, and is the part of a class that defines methods and instance variables that an object of that class has access to. Also, properties are set here.
- *implementation*: usually denoted with ".m" file extension, and is the part of a class that details what the functions and properties defined in the interface, do.

Hope this helped. Again, I'm pretty much brand new to this as well, so the vets, feel free to correct any of the information, as this came from the top of my head.
~Carpetfizz